# Securely transmit password information

Tags: https, passwords, ldap

I work as a student web developer for my computer science department and I've been asked to look into a modification of our password reset procedure for linux accounts.  Currently users will log in with their university credentials (via Active Directory) and after being authenticated they get a temporary password through email which they are forced to change as soon as they log in.  This way eben if the temporary password it intercepted there is a very short time span in which it could even be used.

Now the idea has been posed that instead of using a temporary password that we might allow the user to pick a new permanent password and set it directly through the web utility.  It is my understanding that https is more of "the best we have" than "a great way to secure information".  Are there any other avenues I can explore for securing the new password so that we can feel comfortable implementing such a system?

Comment: Could you not instead authenticate the linux accounts against AD? Assuming you have the eduPerson schema in place on AD, you could filter users with the eduPersonEntitlement attribute. This would provide a more unified experience for the user and might save you some work.

Comment: The Linux accounts validate against our own LDAP server (OpenLDAP I believe). Other than binding and authentication university IT won't let us near their AD servers. (Gotta love the bureaucracy).

Comment: Well second best would certainly be what you're describing. You can certainly trust HTTPS to secure the communication of the password between the user's browser and your web server. It's definitely better than emailing a temporary password.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you communicate with a server over [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https) and the private key of the server isn't exposed to someone else, you can be sure that anything you transfer (e.g. the new password) can only be decrypted by the server. Additionally the server certificate assures, that the server you are communicating with, really is the server you want to communicate with.

So, using HTTPS provides authentication and prevents eavesdropping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Active Directory, it is my understanding that the Password Modify Extended Operation (which requires the existing password) is not supported. Therefore, the password must be changed with the LDAP modify request. One solution would be to use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) with a web application to execute the LDAP modify with the new password. The modify request should be transmitted over a secure connection, or a non-secure connection promoted to a secure connection using the StartTLS extended operation.

#### see also

- [AD password change](http://www.dirmgr.com/blog/2010/8/26/ldap-password-changes-in-active-directory.html)
- [Using ldapmodify](https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/) - this article is about the command line utility `ldapmodify` but the concepts are useful.